# screen capture of webpage only using javascript

Tags: javascript

> > I want to capture OSM(Open Street Map) displayed within div tag on my web page by clicking a button on the page.
> >     Can any one assist me how can I achieve this using JavaScript, please.
> >
> > Thanks in advance.

Comment: had u tried something

Comment: Try this http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: but this is not working in ie

Comment: @Sachin Puranik. Read the doc

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lucky23/9x976r14/ 
Any help to run this correctly.